# while using sumifs, how can i have multiple options for a particular criterion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried using the below formula but not getting correct value:
=SUM(SUMIFS(payments!$D$2:$D$1776,payments!$A$2:$A$1776,A7,payments!$B$2:$B$1776,{H7,H7-1,H7+1}))

H7 is a date.
Can anybody please help with how this works?

Comment: You need to show a sample data to what you are referring to. Also show what is your actual output vs the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIFS` does not work with an array, you have to use `SUMPRODUCT`

Try `=SUMPRODUCT(payments!$D$2:$D$1776*(payments!$A$2:$A$1776=A7)*(payments!$B$2:$B$1776={H7,H7-1,H7+1}))`